# Forward slash automatically converted to backward slash in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

In my Cakephp v2 site I have uploaded some files with apostrophe. But when I try to access the files. Showing file missing error. Other files do not having apostrophe display properly.

Ex:

Missing url :
http://example.com/app/webroot/doc/files/1460440189Alezuyo%20sushil/'s%20ID.pdf

Actual url should be

http://example.com/app/webroot/doc/files/1460440189Alezuyo%20sushil\'s%20ID.pdf

Problem with Forward slash automatically converted to backward slash. Can I do something on routing or htaccess.

Comment: _“Actual url should be [...]”_ - no, it should not. If you need to have an apostrophe in your file names/URLs, then you should properly URL-encode it, not try any nonsense with backward slashes - those are not an “escape character” or anything like that in a URL context to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand. For future upload I do same but for existing/uploaded file is there any alternative or I need to do manually.